# Conditional Sorting on 2 fields in Elastic Search Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have type in my data, if
type is A then i need to sort by price1
and if type is B then i need to sort by price2,

so in c# NEST how we can write query for this?

```
{
  "test": {
    "mappings": {
      "listings": {
        "properties": {
          "productname": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ptype": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "price1": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "price2": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have two types in elasticsearch index?

Comment: I have one field "list type", which can be either A or B.

Comment: May you share your index mapping and sample document?

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
_elasticClient.SearchAsync<ListingsModel>(s => s
    .Type(type)
    .Sort(o => 
    {
        if(type == "A")
            return o.OnField("price1");
        else
            return o.OnField("price2");
    })
    //rest of query
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I was able to do was something like this

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost.fiddler:9200");
            var indexName = "test_index";

            ElasticClient db = new ElasticClient(uri);

            db.DeleteIndex(indexName);

            foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new A { Price1 = random.NextDouble() * 1000 }))
            {
                db.Index(item, inx => inx.Index(indexName));
            }

            foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new B { Price2 = random.NextDouble() * 1000 }))
            {
                db.Index(item, inx => inx.Index(indexName));
            }

            //db.IndexMany(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new A { Price1 = random.NextDouble() * 1000 }), indexName); When using this got nothing back since the query was too fast after index
            //db.IndexMany(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new B { Price2 = random.NextDouble() * 1000 }), indexName);

            var data = db.Search<JObject>(q =>
                q.Index(indexName)
                .Size(20)
                .Type("")
                .Sort(s => s.Script(scd => scd
                    .Type("number")
                    .Script(sc => sc
                        //.Inline(@" doc['price1']?  doc['price1'] : doc['price2']") if no price1 field in object B then you can use this and no need for TypeIndex
                        .Inline(@"doc['typeIndex'] == 0?  doc['price1'] : doc['price2']")// typeIndex must be a number lucene has no string literal support
                        .Lang("expression")
                        ).Order(SortOrder.Descending))));


            Console.WriteLine("DONE");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [ElasticsearchType(Name="A")]
    public class A 
    {
        [Number]
        public int TypeIndex { get { return 0; } }

        [Number]
        public double Price1 { get; set; }
    }

    [ElasticsearchType(Name = "B")]
    public class B
    {
        [Number]
        public int TypeIndex { get { return 1; } }

        [Number]
        public double Price2 { get; set; }
    }
```

You could do it with groovy but I don't know how good will it performe. expression are on by default and they use [lucene](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-expression.html). I do think it is a bit "hacky" but hope helps a bit.